# Motorolla Device Scanning Issue

Tags: c#, symbols, motorola

I am developing in C# for the Motorola device "MC67" and I have having issues with initialising the scanner.

The code I am using seems to be generic as I have found similar examples all over the Internet; for reference here is the code that is causing me problems:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize the reader.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    public override bool InitReader()
    {
        Logger.Instance.Debug("InitReader");

        bool result = false;

        //      Logger.Instance.AddToDebuggerLog("Symbol.InitReader");

        // If reader is already present then fail initialize
        if (this._MyReader != null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        try
        {
            // Create new reader, first available reader will be used.
            this._MyReader = new Symbol.Barcode.Reader();

            // Create reader data
            this._MyReaderData = new Symbol.Barcode.ReaderData(
              Symbol.Barcode.ReaderDataTypes.Text,
              Symbol.Barcode.ReaderDataLengths.MaximumLabel);

            // Enable reader, with wait cursor
            this._MyReader.Actions.Enable();

            if ((GetDeviceType() != DeviceTypes.SymbolMC3070) && (GetDeviceType() != DeviceTypes.SymbolMC3090BT))
            {
                this._MyReader.Parameters.Feedback.Success.BeepTime = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                this._MyReader.Parameters.Feedback.Success.BeepTime = 50;
            }

            SetScannerDecoderTypeToUseWithScanSys();

            result = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Something has gone wrong Initializing barcode reader etc

            // Log Exception
            Logger.Instance.Exception("InitReader", ex);

            // Ensure reader is Disposed
            if (_MyReader != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    _MyReader.Dispose();
                }
                catch
                {
                    // Just incase something goes wrong
                    Logger.Instance.Error("Error Disposing MyReader in InitReader Exception");
                }
                _MyReader = null;
            }

            // Ensure ReaderData is Disposed
            if (_MyReaderData != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    _MyReaderData.Dispose();
                }
                catch
                {
                    // Just incase something goes wrong
                    Logger.Instance.Error("Error Disposing MyReaderData in InitReader Exception");
                }
                _MyReaderData = null;
            }

            // null the EventHandler
            _MyEventHandler = null;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

My problem is that when the above method is called, the following line produces an exception error:

```
this._MyReader.Actions.Enable();
```

The exception is "OperationFailureException" and the error message mentions "Get all supported attributes failed : E_SCN_INVALIDIOCTRL"

Now the strange thing is that I am able to actually use the scanner on the device correctly, so I can scan barcodes and read the data even with this exception but the fact that it is happening concerns me so I am trying to prevent it.

Does anyone have any idea why I am getting the exception or any suggestions of things I can try?

Answer (score 0):

This is a "handled" exception in the Symbol library.  Just turn off the breakpoint for thrown exception-- Ctrl-Alt-E, in the row "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" uncheck the box under "Thrown".  Unfortunately if you're trying to debug an exception that isn't working correctly, you just gotta keep pressing play every time this exception comes up.

I haven't found a way to make it stop throwing the exception though...  I'd really like to be able to turn off whatever feature is failing.

Comment: This seems to be the same thing that I am seeing; yes I could just uncheck the tick box and the exception is no longer thrown but I don't like the fact that it does occur so ideally I would like to prevent it from happening.